# C-string initialization results in unexpected placement of null character

Tags: c++, initialization, c-strings

Can anyone explain to me why the following script outputs 27 on my machine?  Why is the \0 character not positioned at index 15 when I initialize a?  Likewise, if I create a pointer to a single character, strlen returns 12 for that pointer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char a[15];
    cout << strlen(a);
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `a`, you only declare it. It will likely be full of garbage data that happened to be in the stack memory area before your `main` function was called.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: The result should have been _42_ actually. You have buggy hardware!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't can explain which result of undefined behavior would be considered  _valid_ or expectable. Take care of your nostrils and be prepared demons flying out there.

Comment: "*Why is the \0 character not positioned at index 15 when I initialize a?*"  --  Maybe by chance position 15 could have been `\0`.  But that doesn't stop the other positions 0 - 14 from having a stray `\0` character, thus the call to `strlen` still wouldn't have given you 15.

Answer (score 0):

variables of local scope are not initialized unless you specify it.

You do not specify an initialization value, thus it's just on the stack, filled with whatever random cruft was there when you entered the function.

Answer (score 0):

`a` doesn't get initialized, it just contains garbage values. That means, the return value of `strlen(a)` will be undefined, anything is possible.